# what is the significance of the word "Sub-problems" in Greedy Method?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms

With respect to Dynamic Programming we make a statement that :

> Greedy algorithm have a local choice of the sub-problems whereas
>   Dynamic programming would solve the all sub-problems and then select
>   one that would lead to an optimal solution.

Now in Dynamic Programming we have some problem with recursive nature which we solve by solving the sub-problems and then obtain the global optimum but in case of Greedy approach we do not solve the problem in any recursive nature rather we find a feasible solution at every stage with the hope of finding optimal solution.

So I am unable to get the notion of sub-problems in case of Greedy Approach .

Comment: It's best to look at some examples. The text is supposed to help you, so if it doesn't, you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example, the problem of *Set Cover*:

> **Set Cover**
>
> Input: Sets $S_1,\ldots,S_m$ whose union is $U$
>
> Output: Minimal-size subset of $\{S_1,\ldots,S_m\}$ whose union is $U$

The well-known greedy algorithm for this problem (which gives a $\ln n$ approximation) proceeds as follows:

- While $U \neq \emptyset$:

  1. Add to the solution the largest set $S_i$.
  2. Remove all elements of $S_i$ from all sets and from $U$.

Having chosen a set $S_i$, we are effectively moving to another Set Cover instance, in which the sets are $T_j := S_j \setminus S_i$, and the universe is $V := U \setminus S_i$.

This new instance is the sub-problem mentioned in your statement. The greedy choice — largest set — is the local choice mentioned in your statement.

To check your understanding, show that this view is appropriate for other well-known greedy algorithms such as Huffman encoding and the greedy algorithm for interval scheduling.

Comment: For completeness: this greedy algorithm doesn't actually compute the optimal set subset, only an approximation. The set cover problem is in fact NP-hard.